# php session is lost when using my IP instead of localhost

Tags: php, session

im using xampp, my session is always lost when im using my IP instead of localhost/
how can i keep the session? it works ok if i use localhost/

```
<?php 
require '/mysqli.php';

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
```

header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

```
$myJson = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$action = $myJson->action;

session_start();
if($action == 'login') {
    $myJson->password ? $role='admin' : $role='encoder';

    $_SESSION['username'] = $myJson->username;
    $_SESSION['role'] = $role;
    $_SESSION['id'] = session_id();

    if($role =='admin'){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='".$myJson->username."' AND `password`='".md5($myJson->password)."'";

        // $_SESSION['status'] = 
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
            $_SESSION['status'] = "Login success.";
        } else {
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
            $_SESSION['status'] = "Login failed.";
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Login success.";
    }

} else if ($action == 'logout') {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION['status'] = "Logged out.";
} else if ($action == 'check' && session_id() == ''){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_SESSION[''];
    $_SESSION['role'] = $_SESSION[''];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_SESSION[''];
    var_dump($_SESSION);
}

echo json_encode($_SESSION);
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the problem here is that a session has a **unique session ID** which is generated with your connection to the server.

therefore if you connect with *localhost* your IP is `127.0.0.1` and if you start the session with your actual ip you have something like: `192.168.0.10` and a **new session ID** is generated and hence started. 
a possible way to workaround this is to enter a host entry into your *host* file.

the question is: what do you want to achieve? Do you switch the URLs while testing? if *yes*, why?

Comment: i was testing on the actual IP and i was not switching URLS. of course i want to achieve one that does not lose the session :)